# how to replace [" with "" in java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a string like this =   `["41020834846 - Yan Oda 1"`  .I want to delete the ( `["` ) in the beginning of the string with replaceAll.

so what should I do?

I have tried  `replaceAll("[\"", "")` but it did not worked.

Comment: Is that pattern  -`["` only at the beginning?

Comment: yes.but I solved the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
String test = "[\"41020834846 - Yan Oda 1";
Log.i("======= Replace String"," :: "+test.replace("[\"", ""));
```

**Output-** `41020834846 - Yan Oda 1`

Comment: silly me I have tried this but forgot the check.but thanks a lot for reminding and answering.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `replace("[\"", "")` instead.

`replaceAll(...)` is for regexp match. If you want to do it with replaceAll you need to escape the symbol `[` used in regular expressions:

```
replaceAll("\\[\"", "")
```

If the string is always at the start exactly like that, just do:

```
.substring(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method:

```
String str = "[\"41020834846 - Yan Oda 1";
str = str.substring(2);
// OR
// str = str.substring(2, str.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `replaceAll("\[\"", "")` since the `[` is part of the regex syntax, thus making you input invalid regex for your case.

Also you can use one of the Apache Commons StringUitls or Guava if you work a lot with text. 
Using StringUtils for example there is [StringUtils#remove(str,remove)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) where for example:

```
 StringUtils.remove("queued", "ue") = "qd"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the

```
replaceAll();
```

instead of this, use the

```
replace();
```

method.
Other way is that Using of String Class methods.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -2):

Try it :

```
 String example = "["41020834846 - Yan Oda 1";
    String pattern = "^(\[\")";
    example = example.replaceAll(pattern,""));
```